# How to get pandas crosstab to sum up values for multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab, contingency

Let's assume we have a table like:

```
id    chr     val1     val2
...    A        2       10
...    B        4       20
...    A        3       30
```

...and we'd like to have a contingency table like this (grouped by `chr`, thus using `'A'` and `'B'` as the row indices and then summing up the values for `val1` and `val2`):

```
       val1    val2    total
A        5      40       45
B        4      20       24
total    9      60       69
```

How can we achieve this?

`pd.crosstab(index=df.chr, columns=["val1", "val2"])` looked quite promising but it just counts the rows and does not sum up the values.

I have also tried (numerous times) to supply the values manually...

```
pd.crosstab(
  index=df.chr.unique(),
  columns=["val1", "val2"],
  values=[
    df.groupby("chr")["val1"],
    df.groupby("chr")["val2"]
  ],
  aggfunc=sum
)
```

...but this always ends up in shape mismatches and when I tried to reshape via NumPy:

```
values=np.array([
  df.groupby("chr")["val1"].values,
  df.groupby("chr")["val2"].values
].reshape(-1, 2)
```

...`crosstab` tells me that it expected 1 value instead of the two given for each row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'chr': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'A'},
 'val1': {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 3},
 'val2': {0: 10, 1: 20, 2: 30}})
# aggregate values by chr
df = df.groupby('chr').sum().reset_index()
df = df.set_index('chr')
# Column Total
df.loc['total', :] = df.sum()
# Row total
df['total'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

Output

```
       val1     val2    total
chr         
A       5.0     40.0    45.0
B       4.0     20.0    24.0
total   9.0     60.0    69.0
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is pivot_table

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['val1','val2'], index=['char'], aggfunc=np.sum)
table['total'] = table['val1'] + table['val2']
```